# Buffy in mental hospital

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

In one of the Buffy episodes, there is a quick flash of a scene where she is in a mental hospital. Was it ever resolved why this scene was shown? I seem to remember the implication being that her whole life was a mental breakdown.

Comment: Any chance the answer below might be accepted?  No new info has turned up for almost two years.

Comment: Go on then, because it's you

Comment: You're a dear.  :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The episode you are referring to is ["Normal Again"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_Again).  It isn't a "quick flash of a scene".  The entire episode is a tug of war between her being in a mental institution (in which the doctor and her parents are trying to convince her that being a slayer is a delusion) and the life we are accustomed to seeing her lead in Sunnydale.

[image]

Ostensibly, the mental institution is the delusion (rather than her life as a slayer), and the visions of the mental institution are brought on after **Buffy is stung by a demon, thereby exposing her to a hallucinogenic venom.**  In-universe, this is why we are seeing these scenes.

That being said, the episode ends in an ambiguous way, so as to suggest that her life as a slayer in Sunnydale might actually be the hallucination.

Out-of-universe, this is what led to the episode in question:

> According to Joss Whedon, this episode was the "ultimate postmodern look at the concept of a writer writing a show", as **it questioned fantastical or inconsistent elements of the show "the way any normal person would".** Whedon added that the episode is intentionally left open to interpretation... "If the viewer wants," Whedon says, "the entire series takes place in the mind of a lunatic locked up somewhere in Los Angeles... and that crazy person is me." Although, "Personally, I think it really happened."

([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_Again), derived from [here](http://www.nytimes.com/2003/05/16/readersopinions/16WHED.html?ex=1185076800&en=7c66de4a5f0e124b&ei=5070).)

Comment: IIRC - the demon didn't bite Buffy - it stabbed her with a needle thing on its arm...

Comment: The *ultimate* postmodern look at the concept of a writer writing a show. *Some*one has a high opinion of himself, *hmmm?*

Comment: @JonClements : Was working off of memory.  Corrected --- thanks.

Comment: @Beta: well, yeah. He created *Buffy the Vampire Slayer*, and wrote and directed many of its best episodes. Opinion is accurately high.